# simple background css issue

Tags: html, css, background

I'm trying to tessellate a .png file I made, in the body of a HTML document.

For the life of my I can't find out why it's not doing it. I've got the image stored locally but for the sake of making a code pen I've uploaded it to imgur.

http://codepen.io/MartinBort/pen/CbwgJ
Relevant code starts at line 5 of the CSS

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h31R.png <-- that's the image

```
body {
background-image: url("https://i.stack.imgur.com/0h31R.png") repeat;
}
```

Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: your issue was the `repeat` background-image can only contain `url` you need to use `background:` if you want to add `repeat` or anything else in one property

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use this

```
body {
background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jy6hCro.png") repeat;
}
```

or this remove repeat in `background-image` and add other style `background-repeat:repeat;` but `background-image` defaoult repeated

```
body {
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/Jy6hCro.png');
     background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Comment: Your second example won't remove the repeat. repeat is default to remove repeat you have to write `no-repeat`.

Answer (score 1):

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jy6hCro.png");
background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

codepen

http://codepen.io/anon/pen/hdBqk

Answer (score 1):

As the other answers suggest, the problem is the `repeat` word in the `backgroung-image` property. You cannot give the repeat property in the image property. If you want to combine them use the `background` property such as:

```
body {
    background: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jy6hCro.png") repeat;
}
```

Or, specify it seperately, such as:

```
body {
    background-image: url("http://i.imgur.com/Jy6hCro.png");
    background-repeat:repeat;
}
```

Hope this helps!